# How to use "weston-keyboard" virtual/on-screen keyboard with a Qt application

Tags: qt, wayland

I have a embedded linux display (Yocto build) that uses the Wayland Weston display compositor, for which I am developing Qt application software, targeting Qt 5.9.4.

My application is running successfully and text input UI fields are working fine with a USB keyboard, however despite a day of Googling and experimentation I can't see any sign of the virtual/on-screen keyboard that is supposedly provided by the Weston compositor.  There is a "weston-keyboard" process running on the display, but there is no sign of a popup on-screen keyboard appearing anywhere.

Does anyone know if there is anything in particular that needs to be done from the application software end to show/activate the virtual keyboard (from my assorted readings I get the impression it should "just work"), or should I be suspecting a flaw in the operating system build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt applications use the Wayland protocol extension, `zwp_text_input_manager_v2`, to communicate to the compositor about the virtual keyboard.

As far as I know it's not supported by Weston (you can check what extension are supported by running `weston-info`.

So if that exact version is not implemented by the compositor, the Qt client will think that the compositor doesn't support it (even though it may implement `zxdg_text_input_manager_v1` and/or `zxdg_text_input_manager_v3`.

For `zwp_text_input_manager_v2`, you could either run kwin, or a Qt Wayland-based compositor. See the `pure-qml` example in the `qwayland` repository for how to do this.

The Qt virtual keyboard can also be run as part of each client by setting QT_IM_MODULE=qtvirtualkeyboard on the client side.

There's [official documentation on the way regarding this](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/236658/5//ALL,unified). Hopefully, it will show up [here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtvirtualkeyboard-deployment-guide.html) after a while.

Comment: `weston-info` run on the device in question is returning 'zwp_text_input_manager_v1'.

I haven't even considered the Qt virtual keyboard at this point.  I'm working on a commercial development that I can't mix GPL code into, so would have to pick up a commercial license.